# When will train() method in easy_seq2seq stop?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm running a RNN demo at https://github.com/suriyadeepan/easy_seq2seq/blob/master/execute.py, everything runs soomthly except I don't know when should it stop.

The train() method in this module (exectue.py) doesn't seem have stop condition. Anyone else has ever run this demo too? How can this method stop? Kill it by yourself? If so, when?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `train()` method will not stop on it's own, as it contains an infinite-loop. The `train()` method periodically saves the model after a certain number of iterations, depending on the settings in `seq2seq.ini`.

You should cancel the training when you are ready (with `CTRL + C`). You can then run the most-recently saved model in 'test' or 'serve' mode. You can change the mode in `seq2seq.ini` and then run `python execute.py` again to run the code in that mode.